# Extract XML content of an IFrame under IE9

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm running with this issue since a week now

I wonder to do something very simple :

Extract the XML content contained within an iframe and consume it within the parent document (*in my case send the XML to an ActiveX for a signature*)

here is a url where to find the the mini 
[project zip](http://goo.gl/7EkvL)

my target browser is *IE9/10*.

**Parent document** :

```
            <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Parapheur 5.0</h1>
            <div class="alert-block">Please use buttons for actions</div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-mini" onclick="javascript:expandViewport('viewport1');">Expand viewport &raquo;</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-mini" onclick="javascript:collapseViewport('viewport1');">Collapse viewport &raquo;</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" onclick="javascript:extractXml('#viewport1');">Extract XML &raquo;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alert-block"></div>
            <iframe id="viewport1" src="xml/data.xml" width="1024px" height=""></iframe>
            <div class="alert-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="alert-info"></div>
```

**application.js** :

```
function extractXml(id,content) {
console.log("Starting extraction of XML from within IFrame : " + id);
/*
var lastIndexOfSlash = document.getElementById(id).src.lastIndexOf("/");
var doc = document.getElementById(id).src.substring(lastIndexOfSlash);
$.get('xml/'+doc,function(xml){
                    console.log(xml);
                });
*/
console.log($(id).contentDocument);}
```

Comment: using chrome console and IE9 console (F12) I'm running this line of code : document.getElementById("viewport1").contentWindow.document which returns an object (my xml) but no way to access that XML

Comment: the following line returns me the xml console.log(document.getElementById("viewport1").contentWindow.document.firstChild.nextSibling.textContent); but runs differently under IE( comparing to chrome according to both consoles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the only way to load the xml from the iframe under IE9 is by the execution of the following line of code.

```
document.getElementById("viewport1").contentWindow.document.firstChi‌​ld.nextSibling.textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the iframe xml in IE9 as below.

```
var frameIE = document.getElementById("yourIframeElementID");
var textXml = frameIE.contentWindow.document.firstChild.innerText;//Get the text
var regex = new RegExp('- <', 'g');
textXml = textXml.replace(regex, "<");
var xml = $.parseXML(textXml);//Use jquery to parse xml
xml = $(responseData);
//Now u can use this xml object to find xml nodes inside it using jquery...
```

I had to use this method when using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`. In this case, IE9 works in compatibility mode and does not even allow access to `window.frames.<your_frame_name>.document.XMLDocument`, and `$("#iframeId").contents()` also does not work.

If you do not have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"... />` tag, you can use the below code:

```
var contents = window.frames.your_frame_name.document.XMLDocument;
var xml = $(contents);
//use this 'xml' object to access its nodes using jquery.
```

But for all of above to work, your frame must be pointing to a resource within same origin or domain.